# What does it mean to be "creative along practical lines of endeavour"?

Tags: meaning, example

A long time ago I received career guidance and that(the quotation withing the question) was advice given. I am a software developer and I always wanted to understand that statement and whether I am actually following that advice I was given decades ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler way to put that might be:

> Be creative but practical.

The admonition there would encourage creativity, but only creativity that might yield concrete results. In programming it would exhort you to create programs that solved, say, real-world problems. In other words, don't spend your time dreaming up fancy, high-falutin' ideas that can never be produced or which have no utility for solving genuine problems.

Comment: Thank you! That definitely makes sense within the context of my career right now.